# Increasing the line thickness in R

Tags: r, kernel-density

I am trying to make a density plot with 2 variables but I need the lines to be thicker. I have used this command:

```
    >print(plot(density(x,na.rm = T),col="blue",lwd=3,main="Text",cex.main=1.2))

    >lines(density(y,na.rm = T),col="purple",lwd=3)
```

Although it did thicken the line, below the command it shows: NULL
What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `print`. Just do:

```
# Sample data
set.seed(2017);
x <- rnorm(100, 2);
y <- rnorm(100, 2, 3);

plot(density(x, na.rm = T), col = "blue", lwd = 3, main = "Text", cex.main = 1.2);
lines(density(y, na.rm = T), col = "purple", lwd = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I have used the print command because I have to submit the plot, the console results and the Rscript - all as a Word document, so that the person receiving can simply copy the code and run in after pasting into the Rscript.

Comment: @Maria Not sure I understand what you mean. Are you talking about an `R Markdown` document? You still don't need a `print` command, when you `knit` a Word document.

Comment: This is what I was asked to do with the document: "please copy and paste your work from the R console into a Word document. Copy both your R code and the results.". If I use the print() option, he should be able to simply copy+paste the word document text into the Rscript and run it to see what I got. Am I understanding it wrong? Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: @Maria To me this sounds like: Copy the R code as you'd use it in an R terminal/RStudio into your Word document. There's no need for `print`. Then include the output, i.e the plot. I have a feeling that there is some misconception about what `print` does. If your lecturer/instructor copies the lines from my solution into an R terminal, he will be able to reproduce your plot.

Comment: @Maria If this answers your question please close the question by setting the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Which argument of plot is responsible of the line thickness?

Comment: @logicbloke `lwd` sets the *l*ine *w*i*d*th